# PHP Heatmap - Large Value difference

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi I have this Query and I'm getting an empty result, Anyone see anything obviously wrong with this?

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;
SELECT sector, SUM((fleetnow)+(fleetsoon)) AS Count
 FROM AEDatabase
 INNER JOIN AEPlayer AS Own ON AEDatabase.owner = Own.id
 INNER JOIN AEPlayer AS Occ ON AEDatabase.occer = Occ.id
WHERE Galaxy='L49' AND (Own.guild='1085' OR Occ.guild='1085')
GROUP BY sector
```

Specific message from MySQL is:
"MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.4441 sec )"

Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Comment: Try debugging the query by stripping it down. Remove the joins, where and group in different combinations.

Comment: Sorry hit enter expecting a new line, and it posted the message.

SELECT sector, SUM((fleetnow)+(fleetsoon)) AS Count FROM AEDatabase INNER JOIN AEPlayer AS Own ON AEDatabase.owner = Own.id WHERE Galaxy='L49' AND Own.guild='1085' GROUP BY sector

Comment: Still need the first one to work unfortunately.

Man that was a very quick reply, was expecting to wait weeks. :) Thanks

Comment: So `INNER JOIN AEPlayer AS Occ ON AEDatabase.occer = Occ.id` doesn't match anything then?

Comment: Thanks :)

SELECT sector, SUM( (
fleetnow
) + ( fleetsoon ) ) AS Count
FROM AEDatabase
INNER JOIN AEPlayer AS Occ ON AEDatabase.occer = Occ.id
WHERE Galaxy = 'L49'
AND Occ.guild = '1085'
GROUP BY sector

Comment: Ahh darn Enter.  The above worked, returned empty set.  So I must be missing something here.  Any idea what?

Comment: My point was that, if that query worked and you look at its result, you'll see that nothing matches `AEDatabase.occer = Occ.id`. Try `SELECT *` so you can see every column in the result, for debugging purposes. As you have not said what the query actually is supposed to do, we have no way of saying if you have constructed it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SQL request is composed correctly according to your business logic, and it returns no data it means, that either AEPlayer doesn't contain related data or AEDatabase doesn't contain any data related to Galaxy='L49'
You should separate all components of your request to determine what exactly collapses the result set.